# How to find all controls in a multi steps Wizard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, wizard

I want to collect automaticaly all informations (i.e. control values) in a asp:wizard with multiple steps. How to do it?
I found an interesting link, but it seams not to work properly: just a few infos about the current step: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4(v=vs.80).aspx

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
    {
        if (childc is Label)
        {
            lblTitre0.Text += ((Label)childc).Text + ",";
        }
    }
}
```

No data shown in lblTitre0 (asp:label)

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot just use the built-in `FindControl()` (e.g. `controlFound = c.FindControl(id);`)

Comment: Yes, my objective is to get (i.e. list) all controls without the obligation to get them one by one, with their name (i.e. id), as their are a lot in my wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:Wizard runat="server" ID="mainWizard">
 <WizardSteps>
  <asp:WizardStep>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl1" Text="Label one" />
  </asp:WizardStep>
  <asp:WizardStep>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl2" Text="Label two" />
  </asp:WizardStep>
 </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGetall" Text="Get All controls" 
            OnClick="btn_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult" />
```

---

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (WizardStep step in mainWizard.WizardSteps)
   {
     foreach (Control cntrl in step.Controls)
     {
        if (cntrl is Label)
          lblResult.Text += ((Label)cntrl).Text + ",";
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you @yogi!

This is the right way for Wizard. I didn't thouth about it.

Just an other question: is it possible to do it **for all control types** in one instruction? For exemple, DropDownList, RadioButtonList, TextBox and not only for Labels?